# Inserting superscript and unicode characters into ggplot axis title

Tags: r, regex, ggplot2

I am trying to write (m·min^-1) as a label for a plot; however, it seem like it doesn't like the interpunct. I've been trying to use:

```
ylab(expression((m ~paste(\U00B7)~ min^{-1} ~ ))
```

This has no luck so far, any suggestions how I can get both the interpunct and superscript into the same label?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these kind of tasks I'd recommend using LaTeX through `latex2exp`

```
library(latex2exp)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = 0), aes(x)) +
    labs(y = TeX("$m \\times min^{-1}$"))
```

[image]

Or using `\cdot` instead of `\times`

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 0), aes(x)) +
    labs(y = TeX("$m \\cdot min^{-1}$"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `expression` in `ggplot` you can do

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, hp)) + geom_point() + 
   ylab(expression((m~"\U00B7"~min^-1)))
```

[image]

or with a bullet

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, hp)) + geom_point() + 
   ylab(expression((m~"\U2022"~min^-1)))
```

[image]